Linear functionals on Von Neumann algebra tensor products
I am reading about the basics of Von Neumann algebra tensor products, and I am a bit confused on how one proves that the tensor product of bounded linear functionals on a VNA extends to the VNA tensor product.

Let $M \subset B(H)$ and $N \subset B(K)$ be Von Neumann algebras.  The Von Neumann algebra tensor product is given by: $$M \overline{\otimes} N := \overline{M \odot N}^{wot} \subset B(H \otimes K).$$  Moreover if $\omega \in M_{*}$, $\eta \in N_{*}$, then there is a unique linear functional $\omega \overline{\otimes} \eta \in (M \overline{\otimes} N)_{*}$ such that $(\omega \overline{\otimes} \eta)(x \otimes y) = \omega(x)\eta(y)$ for all $x \in M$ and $y \in N$.

I have several questions from this, as someone coming from $C^{*}$-algebras.

From the definition, it follows that $M \overline{\otimes} N = \overline{M \otimes_{\min} N}^{wot} = (M \otimes_{\min} N)''$ correct? This should just follow from the WOT being weaker than the norm topology inherited from $B(H \otimes K)$.

I was able to show if $\omega \in M_{*}$ and $\eta \in N_{*}$, then by $\sigma$-weak (or ultraweak if you prefer) continuity, there are sequences $(\xi^{\omega}_n)_n, (\tau^{\omega}_n)_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}, H)$ and $(\xi^{\eta}_n)_n, (\tau^{\eta}_n)_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}, K)$ such that: $$\omega(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle x \xi^{\omega}_n, \tau^{\omega}_n \rangle, \: \: \eta(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle y \xi^{\eta}_n, \tau^{\eta}_n \rangle, \: \: x \in M, \: y \in N.$$  Hence, it's clear that by relabeling and using that $(\omega \odot \eta)(x \otimes y) = \omega(x)\eta(y)$ we get: $$(\omega \odot \eta)(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \langle z \zeta^{(1)}_j, \zeta^{(2)}_j \rangle_{H \otimes K} \: \: \forall z \in M \odot N$$ where $(\zeta^{(1)}_j)_j, (\zeta^{(2)}_j)_j \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}, H \otimes K)$.  However, this only shows that $\omega \odot \eta$ extends to $\overline{M \odot N}^{\sigma-wot}$, but I don't know why $\overline{M \odot N}^{\sigma-wot}$ should equal $\overline{M \odot N}^{wot}$ in general.  How do you show that $\omega \odot \eta$ extends to all of $M \overline{\otimes} N$ from here?

If you just take $\omega,\eta$ to be in $M^{*}, N^{*}$ resp., how do you show the tensor product $\omega \odot \eta$ admits an extension to $M \overline{\otimes} N$?  This doesn't seem as straight forward to me as extending bounded linear functionals $\phi,\psi$ on $C^{*}$-algebra $A,B$ to $A \otimes_{\min} B$, since you additionally have to take a weak closure.  What I don't get about this, is that if you have $\omega \in M^{*}$ and $\eta \in N^{*}$, are you trying to show $\omega \odot \eta$ is weakly continuous to get a functional $\omega \otimes \eta$ on $\overline{M \odot N}^{wot} = M \overline{\otimes} N$?  Is this then a norm continuous linear functional on this set, or is it weakly continuous on $M \overline{\otimes} N$?  In the latter case, this doesn't prove that $\omega \overline{\otimes} \eta \in (M \overline{\otimes} N)^{*}$..


$\textbf{Edit:}$ Sorry, (3) is nonsense, as if you show $\omega \odot \eta$ is weakly continuous on $M \odot N$, then the extension will be weakly continuous on $M \overline{\otimes} N$ and hence norm continuous.  I guess my (3) should be asking then is if all weakly continuous elements of $(M \overline{\otimes} N)^{*}$ are somehow related to $$\text{span}\{\omega \overline{\otimes} \eta \: | \: \omega \in M^{*}, \eta \in N^{*} \} \subset (M \overline{\otimes} N)^{*}?$$


Yes.
First of all, your extension already applies to all operators on $B(H \otimes K)$, so it’s not just extended to the $\sigma$-WOT closure. Regardless, the $\sigma$-WOT closure and the WOT closure of $M \odot N$ are the same. This follows from Kaplansky density theorem, which says that for a $\ast$-subalgebra $A \subset B(H)$, the unit ball of $A$ is SOT dense in the SOT closure of $A$. Since the SOT topology and the $\sigma$-SOT topology coincide on the unit ball, this shows the SOT closure of $A$ equals its $\sigma$-SOT closure. Then by Hahn-Banach, the SOT closure of $A$ equals its WOT closure, and similarly the $\sigma$-SOT closure of $A$ equals its $\sigma$-WOT closure. Now, apply this to $A = M \odot N$.
It still admits an extension, but there’s no reason for this extension to be “natural” or unique anymore. (And it certainly will not be weakly continuous.) The most boring way is just take $\omega \otimes \eta$ on $M \otimes_{\text{min}} N$ and extend using Hahn-Banach. A somewhat more natural way is as follows: for $x \in M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N$, let $\omega \otimes \text{Id}_N(x) \in N = (N_\ast)^\ast$ be given by $\varphi(\omega \otimes \text{Id}_N(x)) = \omega(\text{Id}_M \otimes \varphi(x))$ for any $\varphi \in N_\ast$ (where $\text{Id}_M \otimes \varphi$ is the unique $\sigma$-WOT continuous extension of the slice map on $M \otimes_{\text{min}} N$). Then take $\omega \otimes \eta(x) = \eta(\omega \otimes \text{Id}_N(x))$. The problem with this approach, I should note, is that you can also do it the other way around, by $\omega \otimes \eta(x) = \omega(\text{Id}_M \otimes \eta(x))$, but the two definitions may not yield the same result.


For the edit, as I noted, $\omega \otimes \eta$, however you extend it, is not going to be weakly continuous if you just assume $\omega \in M^\ast$ and $\eta \in N^\ast$. However, there is a description of $\sigma$-weakly continuous linear functionals on $M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N$ - they are exactly the norm-closure of $\text{span}\{\omega \otimes \eta: \omega \in M_\ast, \eta \in N_\ast\}$ in $(M \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N)^\ast$.

Okay thank you, as for my edit on (3), what can one say about the weakly continuous linear functionals?

@Isochron I’ve edited my answer to address that.
